# How to discern vector<> from map<> in nested list initialization?

Tags: c++, constructor, sfinae, constructor-overloading

Consider a class defined as:

```
class C {
    public:
    C(std::vector<std::string>) {};           // (1)
    C(std::map<std::string, std::string>) {}; // (2)
};
```

Then two instances of it, created using list initializers like:

```
C A({ "A", "B" });
C B({ { "A", "B" }, { "C", "D" } });
```

I would expect object `A` to use the `(1)` constructor and object `B` going through `(2)`. But that is not the case and I get the following output: `error: call to constructor of 'C' is ambiguous`.

Furthermore, if I try to declare these instances like:

```
C A = { "A", "B" };
C B = { { "A", "B" }, { "C", "D" } };
```

It fails with this instead: `error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'C'`.

What is going on?

How may I achieve the intended behavior? ( `A -> (1)`, `B -> (2)` ) Perhaps using SFINAE in some way?

Comment: You can check it out here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Iwe1kaWpPODC8sY6

Comment: Only way I can think of is explicitly calling the vector and map constructors, but it kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: @sashang Yes indeed, the point is having **fancy** code ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved what you want in the following way:

```
class C {
    public:
    C(std::vector<std::string>) { std::cout << "here1" << std::endl; }           // (1)
    C(std::map<std::string, std::string>) { std::cout << "here2" << std::endl; } // (2)
};

int main()
{
    C A = C( { {"A"}, {"B"} });
    C B = C( std::map<std::string, std::string> { {"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"} } );
    // or C B = C( { std::make_pair("A", "B"), std::make_pair("C", "D") } );
}
```

EDITED (using unified initialization)

Comment: Thank you @Tetix but the point is to avoid doing that and use the initializer_lists as they should be.

Comment: @almosnow There is no way around that. The second line is the closest you can get afaik.